# How to add logo to Bootstrap's affixed nav

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, nav, affix

I'm trying to add a smaller version of my site logo to Bootstrap's affixed nav bar when the user scrolls.

Here is my [site](http://bootstrapdino.tumblr.com/).

This is what I've been working on so far... I've tried adding to the the nav.affix with the smaller logo but it hasn't worked. Am I on the right path?

```
#nav.affix {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index:10;
background: rgb(255, 255, 255) transparent;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
#nav #nav-img {
background-image:url(http://static.tumblr.com/bw1wxme/rOYn2c6na/logo-small.jpg);
}
#nav.affix #nav-img {
display:inline-block;
}
#sidebar.affix-top {
position: static;
}
#sidebar.affix {
position: fixed;
top: 180px;
}
```

Here is [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N7GGM/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can do it a few different ways.

May want to try looking at some of these suggestions:

[CSS Approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9922018/1162192)

[HTML Approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9894051/1162192)

**Edit:**

You can do something like this in javascript:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var height = $(this).scrollTop();
   var brand = $("#brand");
   if (height > 100){
     brand.show();   
   }
   else{
      brand.hide();
   }
});
```

I have updated your jsfiddle with some changes: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N7GGM/6/)
It isn't completely working with layout included but it does what you are expecting. I added a div in your html with the id and class of Brand. I then set the background to the url you have for the logo. I also set it to hidden by default. When you scroll the logo should appear and disappear when you scroll back up to the top.

Comment: I want the logo to appear on the navbar after the people has begun to scroll tho